URL is not opening on click on teams action card button
I'm trying to create action card button called Acknowledge. The button is visible, but after clicking I want it to go the requested url. I'm using go team notifier SDK.
Below is my code:
card.PotentialActions = append(card.PotentialActions, &messagecard.PotentialAction{
        //Type: "Action.OpenUri",
        Type: "ActionCard",
        Name: "Ack",
        PotentialActionActionCard: messagecard.PotentialActionActionCard{
            Actions: []messagecard.PotentialActionActionCardAction{
                {
                    Type: "ActionCard",
                    Name: "Acknowledge",
                    PotentialActionOpenURI: messagecard.PotentialActionOpenURI{

                        Targets: []messagecard.PotentialActionOpenURITarget{
                            {
                                OS:  "default",
                                URI: "https://google.com",
                            },
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    })

Unfortunately, it is not working.
